# Can I use Kendo UI and Webix on same project?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, webix

I need to migrate an app to HTML 5 and I'm researching HTML 5 frameworks. So far I have Webix and Kendo ui as the 2 finalists.
Now, each one has something that I need to use and that is better than on the other, so, I was thinking about using both of them if possible.
So far the only related comment I have found is this [Webix and KendoUI](https://github.com/telerik/jquery-ui-vs-kendo-ui/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing to consider with regard to styling - Kendo UI uses the content box model, while Webix uses the border box model.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

This can cause problems when nesting components from the two libraries - the ones inside may end up with broken layout due to inherited opposite box model styles.